# Changing the include format from #include "{path}/file.h" to #include "file.h" fix the error?

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgrade xcode to 7.3 and it start throwing file not found errors I tried many solutions but I can't fix that issue, Finally I fixed it by changing

```
#include "Connection/ICommunicator.h"
```

to

```
#include "ICommunicator.h"
```

I can easily implement this change to all other files throwing the same kind of error, but that seem to be a not good solution. If you guys know the way to fix this share with me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem is the `Header Search Path` in your target's build settings. This can happen if you copy library headers directly to your project instead of referencing them via `Header Search Path`.

**Example**

Let's say `ICommunicator.h` resides in the folder `/A/B/Connection/ICommunicator.h` then your Header Search Path should be `/A/B/`. If you set it to `/A/B/Connection` then all `#include` with a relative path such as `#include "Connection/ICommunicator.h"` point to the wrong path namely `/A/B/Connection/Connection/ICommunicator.h`.

**Solution**

Reference the headers via `Header Search Path` in your build settings.